# How to write a method for a jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, function, plugins

I've written a fairly basic jQuery plugin that takes an unordered list and creates a nice looking multi-selectable list. Calling it 'multiSelector', the plugin declaration looks like this:

```
jQuery.fn.multiSelector = function(options) {
    // plugin code
}
```

The plugin actually runs on a containing div with an unordered list inside (for CSS reasons, among others), so a typical use of this plugin looks like this:

```
var $listDiv = $('#listDiv') // div that contains unordered list
$listDiv.multiSelector();
```

It's working great, so I'm not having any problems *creating* the plugin. However, what I'd like to do now is provide the user with a way to get all selected items from their list. I've looked online for how to create functions from this plugin, and I can't really seem to find any ways to extend it with a function.

What would be great is to do something like this, where 'itemArray' is an array of strings based on the list item's id (or something):

```
var itemArray = $listDiv.multiSelector().getSelected();
```

I realize my logic here is probably way off, but I'm just looking for some guidance on how to accomplish this. Maybe I need to write a new jQuery function to handle this specific task, or maybe I can still tack it onto this multiSelector plugin somehow. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest adding the option to call a method as a parameter of the plugin.  This is the way most (all?) jQuery UI plugins handle it.

```
jQuery.fn.multiSelector = function( options ) {
   if (typeof options === "string") {
      if (options == "selected") {
         ...return the selected elements
      }
      return null;
   }

   options = $.extend( {}, $.fn.multiSelector.defaults, options );

   ... rest of plugin body...
}
```

Then call it as

```
var selected = $('.selector').multiSelector('selected');
```

Comment: Actually, *most* plugins return the dom elements being modified (`#listdiv` in the OP's example). This allows for function chaining. Your approach is still valid though.

Comment: @Joel -- Sorry if I wasn't clear.  Yes, the plugin should return jQuery, except when passed a method name to execute.  So, without parameters or when passed an options object, it works like normal and sets up the plugin on the jQuery elements passed in.  When passed a method name on a set of elements that have already been set up using the plugin, it executes the method and returns the method's results.

Comment: @tvanfosson, thanks for the answer. This is most likely the approach I will use. But I'm wondering if there should be an 'else' after the `if (typeof options === "string") {`, just to handle the rest of the logic in the case 'options' is in fact a list of options and not the method call. What do you think?

Comment: There is an "implicit" else -- if it doesn't take the if, then it simply continues.  If it does take the if, then it always makes an early return from the function.  That may not be clear since I couldn't fill in the details about how the selected elements are returned, but it should involve returning from the function.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess, to me, returning early from a function feels a little clunky. I would just like to see a full chain of logic be run through, rather than having multiple return points from the same path. But that's just me. The way presented should work perfectly fine, and it's what I'll use. Thanks again!

Comment: @Mega Matt -- in some ways I agree with you, but (1) it's also a somewhat clunky, albeit idiomatic way of invoking a function on a plugin, (2) invoking the function is clearly outside the main logic of plugin set up, and (3) it saves some, IMO, unnecessary indenting in the actual plugin set up code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your `multiSelector` function return an object that contains a `getSelected` function.

For example:

```
jQuery.fn.multiSelector = function(options) {
    var self = this;

    return {
        getSelected: function() { 
            return self.children('.Selected');
        },
        //Other methods
    };
}
```

Note that within the returned methods, the `this` keyword will refer to the object ypu returned, not the original jQuery object.  To work around this, you'll need to save a reference to the original `this` object (`self` in my example)

Also note that this will break method chaining, meaning that you won't be able to write `$(...).multiSelector().fadeIn()`.  (Obviously)

Comment: Bad idea; by jQuery convention you should always return the jQuery object for method chaining.

Comment: There are some plugins that do it this way.

Comment: @meagar: except that makes that the OP wouldn't be able to do what he wants. Not every jQuery method, let alone plugin, returns the jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

If your plugin returns a jQuery object, then you'd just write another jQuery function to do your "getSelected" operation.

Answer (score 0):

I typically see properties implemented like this:

$listDiv.multiselector('option', 'property'); // get
   $listDiv.multiselector('option', 'property', 'value'); // set

And I'd imagine you could do something similar with a 'selected' property.  Kind of cumbersome, I realize.

As an example, see [UI/Droppable's "methods"](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#methods), which are all accessed via `.droppable("method_name")`.

What you shouldn't do, is return an object that has a getSelected() method, as several answers are suggesting (unless you add said method to the jQuery object). JQuery plugins are expected to return the jQuery object, and deviating from this will cause you grief in the long run, and make your code harder to use.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, plugins will usually provide this functionality by allowing the user to pass in a specific string as an argument to the plugin method that will cause the plugin to return something other than the usual jQuery object. For example,

```
$('#listDiv').multiSelector('getSelected') // will return an array of strings
```